# Python script not running on ready made django vmware image

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django

I am using turnkey image for python django
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/django

When i open the page by ip adress the home page open ok

Now i tried to made the simple python file inside the wwwroot to check but apache is not executing it.
it asks me to download it

THe code of file is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
print 'Hello, world!\n'
```

Its the pre made vmware image and django is working. How can i check my example

Answer (score 0):

By default, CGI scripts must be placed in `cgi-bin/`, must be executable, and must not be world-writable.

Comment: DO you mean i have to create a folder called cgi-bin because currently the default directory of django is /var/www/django-sites/httpdocs . i just want to display hello on web browser. Also then how can i see the django site , i think that is also python and that is not insdie cgi-bin.

Answer (score 0):

chmod 755 the script

If that doesn't work, try putting the following in .htaccess:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

If that doesn't work, try putting those in a Directory block in your VirtualHost config and restart apache:

```
<Directory /path/to/webroot/>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi 
</Directory>
```

Then you need to do:

VirtualHost Config:

```
<Directory /path/to/webroot/>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
</Directory>
```

test.wsgi
    def application(environ, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK',[('Content-type','text/html')])
        return ['Hello World!']

Comment: i will try that but one thing worries me is that i want to run python via web using mod_wsgi , why i need to enable cgi-bin for that

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't run as CGI. Grep around `/etc/apache2` to see where `/var/www/django-sites/apps` is configured. The configuration file should be named `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/django` or similar, and Django is configured with a `WSGIScriptAlias` directive.